# Populate Checkbox from Database Query

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to check a check box, if the value for that field is 1 in the database.

I have:

```
<?php 

$selectedSPK=$_POST['SPKSelect'];
$assigned = $_POST['Sales_Exec'];
$date = $_POST['DateSelect'];

if ($selectedSPK) {
    $Priorityquery = "SELECT  Priority FROM Data WHERE SPKCustNo  = '$selectedSPK' ";
    $Priorityresult = mysql_query($Priorityquery);
    $row = mysql_fetch_array($Priorityresult);
    $checked = $Priorityresult['Priority'];
}
?>
<input name="PriorityCheckBox" type="checkbox" value="1" 
<?php if ($checked == 1) echo ' checked'; ?> />
```

but not getting any joy, any ideas?

Comment: you aren't using the result data...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

You were not using the row returned by the query...

```
<?php 
    $selectedSPK=$_POST['SPKSelect'];
    $assigned = $_POST['Sales_Exec'];
    $date = $_POST['DateSelect'];
    if ($selectedSPK)
    {
        $Priorityquery = "SELECT  Priority FROM Data WHERE SPKCustNo  = '$selectedSPK' ";
        $Priorityresult = mysql_query($Priorityquery);
        $row = mysql_fetch_array($Priorityresult);
        //$checked = $Priorityresult['Priority']; // <------ this is where you went wrong...
        $checked = $row['Priority']; // <------ this will fix where u went wrong!
    }
    ?>
    <input name="PriorityCheckBox" type="checkbox" value="1" <?php if ($checked == 1){echo ' checked'; }?>
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks a lot Chris, new to this so it's tricky to get this stuff right, worked like a charm though, much appreciated, and thanks for showing me where I went wrong.

Comment: No worries, we all started somewhere :)

Answer (score 1):

You should use

```
<?php if ($checked == 1){echo "checked='checked'"; }
```

and also

```
$checked = $Priorityresult['Priority'];
```

to

```
 $checked = $row['Priority'];
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you have one mistake... Try this

```
<input name="PriorityCheckBox" type="checkbox" value="1" <?php if ($row['Priority'] == 1) echo ' checked'; ?> />
```

Answer (score 0):

Try it this way

```
<input name="PriorityCheckBox" type="checkbox" value="1" <?php if ($checked == 1) echo "checked='checked'"; ?> />
```

Answer (score 0):

change

```
<?php if ($checked == 1) echo ' checked'; ?>
```

to

```
<?php if ($checked == 1) echo ' checked="checked"'; ?>
```

and `$checked = $Priorityresult['Priority'];` to `$checked = $row['Priority'];`

Answer (score 0):

It should be `checked="checked"`

```
<?php if ($checked == 1) echo "checked='checked'"; ?>
```